# Exporting from Excel to Access error

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010, vba

I am trying to export a table from Excel to a table in an Access DB, but I keep getting an error "Database or Object is read only".  Here is the code in qestion.

```
    dbWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    dbWS = Application.ActiveSheet.Name
    dsh = "[" & dbWS & "$]"

    Set DB = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    dbPath = "\\Corpaa.aa.com\CampusHome\IOCADHome02\758673\Projects\Global Analysis Tool\MX Analysis DB\Global Line MX Hub Review DB.accdb"
    scn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

    DB.Open scn

    DB.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblNewSchedule;"

    SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO tblNewSchedule "
    SQLSelect = "SELECT * "
    SQLFrom = "FROM [Excel 8.0; HDR=YES; DATABASE= " & dbWB & "]." & dsh & " "

    strQry = SQLInsert & SQLSelect & SQLFrom & ";"
   DB.Execute strQry
   DB.Close
```

The `DELETE` qry executes just fine with no errors.  The problem is the `strQry` execution.  I believe it is refrencing that the WB is read-only, but I am running the code from the WB.  I am running Office 2010.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Should your `SQLFrom = ...` line not end `& dbWS & " "` ? You have used `dsh` which I can't see?

Comment: sorry, I accidently deleted that line.  I have edited the code with the `dsh` line.

Comment: Have you tried `Debug.Print strQry` before the `Execute` to check for anything obvious?

Comment: I don't see any issues there.  Here is the result of the `Debug.Print`.  `INSERT INTO tblNewSchedule SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0; HDR=YES; DATABASE= \\Corpaa.aa.com\CampusHome\IOCADHome02\758673\Global Line MX Analyzing Prep Tool - MMR Version 00 08-21-16.xlsm].[LastRanSchedule$];`

Comment: Yeah, looks good. The question is, is it unable to read the data from Excel, or write the data to Access? Can you try the `DB.Execute` without the `SQLInsert` part so that it just attempts to read/SELECT the data? If it errors, then at least you have narrowed it down..?

Comment: it still gave the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, after continuing my search, I discovered a different approach that worked perfectly.  I found it on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620860/run-time-error-unrecognized-database-while-exporting-data-from-excel-2010-to-acc?rq=1)

Here is my new working code.  Thanks for the assistance.

```
    dbWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    dbWS = Application.ActiveSheet.Name
    dsh = "[" & dbWS & "$]"

    Set DB = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    dbPath = "\\Corpaa.aa.com\CampusHome\IOCADHome02\758673\Projects\Global Analysis Tool\MX Analysis DB\Global Line MX Hub Review DB.accdb"
    scn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

    DB.Open scn

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim r As Long
    Dim y As Long

    y = TWB.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    r = TWB.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

    DB.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblNewSchedule;"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "tblNewSchedule", DB, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

    For i = 2 To y
        With rs
            .AddNew
                For j = 1 To r
                    fName = TWB.Cells(1, j)
                    fData = TWB.Cells(i, j)
                    .Fields(fName) = fData
                Next j
        End With
    Next i

   DB.Close
```

Comment: Another note for anyone looking at this for answers in the future.  To run queries in the DB from Excel with this approach, use the following code: `DB.qryName`.  This works for queries that were built and saved within the DataBase, not the ones built within VBA.  you can also run the SQL straight from the WB as well using: `DB.Execute ("SQLCode")`.  I hope this helps.